# Data does not load dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Datacheck.jsx below

```
function DeckCheck() {
  const [holder, setHolder] = useState("");
  const [deck, setDeck] = useState(null);
  const [cardDisplay, setCardDisplay] = useState(null);
  const [cardCount, setCardCount] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const cards = [];
    deck?.forEach(async (e) => cards.push(await cardCounter(e)));
    setCardCount(cards);
  }, [deck]);


  const clear = () => {
    setHolder("");
    setDeck(null);
    setCardDisplay([]);
    document.getElementById("deckInput").value = "";
  };

  const showCard = () => {
    if (cardDisplay === null) return;
    if (cardDisplay[0]?.image_uris) {
      return (
        <img
          src={cardDisplay[0]?.image_uris?.normal}
          alt=""
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.target.src === cardDisplay[0]?.image_uris?.normal
              ? (e.target.src = cardDisplay[1]?.image_uris?.normal)
              : (e.target.src = cardDisplay[0]?.image_uris?.normal);
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    return <img src={cardDisplay?.image_uris?.normal} alt="" />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="deck">
      <div className="inputsDisplay">
        <div className="inputArea">
          <textarea
            placeholder="Paste deck here. Should be pasted in MTGO format."
            id="deckInput"
            onChange={(e) => setHolder(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <div className="buttons">
            <button
              onClick={() =>
                holder !== "" ? setDeck((prev) => reform(holder)) : null
              }
            >
              Submit
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => clear()}>Reset</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <PowerLevel />

        <div id="carded">{showCard(cardDisplay)}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="cardsList">
        {!deck ? "Enter your cards above" : null}
        {deck?.map((e, index) => (
          <DeckCard inputs={e} key={index} setCardDisplay={setCardDisplay} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <DataBar cardCount={cardCount} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Databar.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function DataBar({ cardCount }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cardCount);
  }, [cardCount]);
  return (
    <div className="dataBar">
      <ul>
        <li>Deck Total:</li>
        <li>Planeswalker:</li>
        <li>Creatures:</li>
        <li>Instants:</li>
        <li>Sorceries:</li>
        <li>Artifacts:</li>
        <li>Enchantments:</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DataBar;
```

I'm unable to figure out a way to get data to dynamically load into the bar. When the cardCount is logged it shows the updated list of everything in the system, but when I run any type of event it will either briefly load data or won't display at all.

I've used several tertiary call and it works in other place of the app.

Here a link to the [github](https://github.com/juarezv90/CrammedMox.git) the git also includes a test load data to load into the search engine in the deckcheck portion of the site

Comment: This: `setCardCount(cards);` pushes the still empty array. Using an async function as forEach callback does not actually await anything before running the next line. You need to use a for loop or map the array to an array of promises and await Promise.all()

Comment: `useEffect(() => { async function load() { const cards = await Promise.all(deck.map(c => cardCounter(c))); setCardCount(cards); } load(); }, [deck]);`